# How to get last record's one value in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Tried to get last record value one but not working. How to do it in mongoose.

Sample data records in mongodb:

```
[
    {
        _id: 5f0c73f69b34214310d0acee,
        name: "Test",
        age: 28,
        voice: "Not Tested"
    },
    {
        _id: 5f0c73f69b34214310d0akke,
        name: "Test2",
        age: 38,
        voice: "Tested"
    }
]
```

Mongoose query:

The value of `voice` property in the last record is "Tested" so I tried to get that value.

```
var Order = mongoose.model(collectionName);
  Order.find({}).sort({ _id: -1 }).limit(1).then((products) => {
    
    products.findOne({voice}, function(err,obj) { 
    
      console.log(obj);//Output should be = Tested
    
    });
});
```

Comment: Schema name is missing there. `var Order = mongoose.model(collectionName,schema name);`

Comment: @NithinKJoy:: schema name is not an issue..I have setup

Comment: Hi @Makizh, what is the value of `obj` your code is currently logging and can you share the value of the `voice` variable you are passing into `products.findOne`

Comment: Got the solution..THANKS

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally, after trying for long 3 hours I found the answer.

```
    User.find({}).sort({_id: -1}).limit(1).then((products) => {
        console.log(products[0].voice)
    })
```

Comment: I want to get the value of voice..Bcoz voice value will be change

Comment: I think now you can understand what i am expecting

Comment: As per I understand you are expecting last record's voice value. It can be either tested or not tested?

Comment: Not "Tested" and "Not tested" only..voice value will be change like  voice: any value

Comment: You have any idea?

Comment: I am working on it. I get _id along with the voice. Will be posting an answer after I get it.

Comment: You got solution?

Comment: Got the solution

Comment: I got the answer, Just try. I think I am late.

Answer (score 2):

Because you doing it wrong. Actually if you needed not last inserted in a collection document, but last updated you should use `timestamps` in your schema ([mongoose docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#timestamps))

So you collection schema should be something like this:

```
let schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    field_one: Number,
    field_two: String,
},{
    timestamps: true
});
```

So you will have not just `field_one` and `field_two`, but also special fields like `createdAt` and `updatedAt`

Then, don't forget to add index for performance at you schema on `updatedAt` field, like this:

```
schema.index({ updatedAt: -1 },{name: 'IndexName'});
```

and only them use:

```
async function LastUpdatedVoice () {
   try {
       let t = await model.findOne({ "field_one": "value" }).select('voice').lean().sort({updatedAt: -1});
       console.log(t);
   } catch (e) {
       console.error(e)
   }
}
```

> *For last inserted document the code will be the same, but instead of `updatedAt` field, you should use `createdAt` field.*

Also, one more thing:

*If you need to updated this document right after it has been found, you could do it without using `lean()` option in my query. And updated the `Mongoose Doc` itself, via:

```
t.voice = new_value
t.save()
```

but I highly recommend you to use [`findOneAndUpdate`](http://findOneAndUpdate) method them.

Comment: Not working: products.findOne({ "field_one": "value" }).select('voice').lean().sort({ updatedAt: -1 })

Comment: It should not, just replace `"field_one": "value"` with your own, `field` and `value` and then call function via `LastUpdatedVoice ()`

Comment: Thanks, i find the solution described a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found it simpler this way.

```
let lastDoc = (await Model.find({}).sort({_id: -1}).limit(1))[0];
console.log(lastDoc);
```

Otherwise, if you use it inside a function, make sure the function is `async`.

```
let docHandler = async () => {
   let lastDoc = (await Model.find({}).sort({_id: -1}).limit(1))[0];
   console.log(lastDoc);
};
```

Comment: won't this throw any error just in case there is not document present in MongoDB?