# Mongoose Latest Record Fetch without sort

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Is there any way to fetch the last created record in mongoose. I have found some blogs but there they used sorting [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62934655/how-to-get-last-records-one-value-in-mongoose). Is there any other way to get last created data without sorting.

Comment: Sorting the records is usually the best way to do this. Is there a particular reason why you want to avoid using sort?

Comment: db.collection.find().skip(db.collection.count() - 1);